# Package dowloaded half when installing

Tags: apt, package-management

This is probably a newbie question. Anyway, I have installed ubuntu using minimal iso. After rebooting and login to ubuntu using my username and password. I install gdm and network manager using

> sudo apt-get install gdm network-manager

In the middle of installation, I happen to push the arrow key which then results a package only downloaded halfway, see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re7wj.jpg),

and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGHTY.jpg). I capture all of them using my phone. My question is, will this be a problem? Or should I reinstall using the same command again? If so, how would I do it? reinstall gdm and network manager without installing the installed package but only installed the one which are not already installed?

Thanks

p.s. after typing the same command again, it says the package gdm and network manager are already up to date.

Comment: there's no problem when you press any key during a install or upgrading apt apps, since this key-combination is not Ctrl-Break or Ctrl-C.

Answer (score 2):

No, unless apt-get gave you an error message, everything is just fine. Error messages are generally starting with `E:` on the start of the line. The key press probably just messed up the printing of the progress.

Apt does sanity checks on downloaded packages, and corrupted packages will **not** be installed. You will get an error.

Furthermore, please paste text as text - don't include screenshots.

Comment: Apt get shows no error. I cant copy the text since I will to reboot again, that's why I use my screenshot. Anyway, thanks for your answer. It is all clear now.